# Custom dialog with with a Contentview that has a layout with 2 buttons - Listener?

Tags: android, button, dialog, listener

From a listview I'm openning an alertdialog (3 options and 2 buttons)

I've this:

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);// ass
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setView(layout);
            builder.setTitle("Select");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(tonos, -1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Option: " + tonos[item]);
                    tone=tonos[item];


                    Button botonOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botOK);

                    try {
                        botonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"button ok");
                                }
                            });

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception " + e);
                    }



                }
            });


            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();




    }
```

Is correct the argument of the second onClick?
I'm crazy testing but I don't find the solution.

Comment: there is no custom dialog layout in you code, here

Comment: In which line do you get NullPointer?

Comment: @Carnal here --> botonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        Button botonOK = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.botOK);
        botonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"button ok");
            }
        });

        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setTitle("Select");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(tonos, -1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Option: " + tonos[item]);
                tone=tonos[item];
            }
        });

        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: what is the getCurrentFocus() for ? can't you use null if it is to go in an AlertDialog ?

Comment: @Carnal doesn't work.. PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) line: 322) I've situated the listener here: builder.setSingleChoiceItems(tones, -1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Option" + tonos[item]);
                HERE}
            }); It's OK????? Thankyou!

Comment: @Héctor Ortiz - what does not work? Seems you are not inflating the way you should, and what exception do you get?

Comment: @Carnal NullPointerException :(

Comment: @Héctor Ortiz - Edit your question to show the code you use and where in code you get NullPointer, easier to see what's going on then.